# Can you explain the differences between the following sentences?

Tags: translation, difference, meaning-in-context, culture

1. **冬天**：`能穿多少穿多少`；**夏天**：`能穿多少穿多少`。
2. 剩女产生的原因有两个:一是`谁都看不上`；二是`谁都看不上`。
3. 女孩给男朋友打电话：如果**你**到了，**我**还没到，`你就等着吧`；如果**我**到了，**你**还没到，`你就等着吧`。
4. 单身的原因:**原来**是`喜欢一个人`，**现在**是`喜欢一个人`。
5. 男人对一个女人有好感的原因:一是`喜欢上这个女人`；二是`喜欢上这个女人`。
6. 男人约会迟到的原因:一是`睡过了`；二是`睡过了`。

Thanks.

Comment: This is actually a very good question, I don't know why people vote to close...

Answer (score 3):

They're puns.

1: Winter: wear as much as possible, summer: wear as little as possible.
多少 means "how much", but could be read as 多+x "how very x", with x here being 少 （little).
2: 看不上 is ambiguous. She won't give anybody a thought. or Nobody gives her a thought.
3: "... then you just keep waiting." vs. "... then you can wait for your punishment."
4: 喜欢一个人 can mean "to like a person", can also mean "to like to be alone" (a verb like 生活 is implied, 一个人 is an adverb here).
5: 喜欢上 can be read as "started to like" vs. "would like to fuck" with 上 being read differently.
6: 睡过了: "he overslept" vs. "has slept (with her) before".

Comment: **2:** just the ambiguity of the subject, nothing to do with fuck. `She won't give anybody a thought.` or `Nobody gives her a thought.` **3:** a. "... then you just keep waiting." b. "... then you can wait for your punishment." **5:**  your interpretation is correct. **6:** "overslept" vs. "has fucked her".

Answer (score 0):

冬天：能穿`多少`穿`多少`；夏天：能穿多`少`穿多`少`。

In winter wear as much as you can; In summer wear as less as you can.

剩女产生的原因有两个:一是`谁`都看不上；二是`谁都看不上`。

Two reasons: nobody likes her; she likes nobody.

女孩给男朋友打电话：如果你到了，我还没到，你就`等着`吧；如果我到了，你还没到，`你就等着`吧。

She tells her BF: if you comes here early than me, just wait; if I come here early than you, watch yourself.

单身的原因:原来是`喜欢一个人`，现在是喜欢`一个人`。

Reason of don't have BF/GF: ago I like single, now I like he/she.(don't like others)

男人对一个女人有好感的原因:一是`喜欢上`这个女人；二是喜欢`上`这个女人。

Reason of a boy likes(or `is fond of`) a girl: he likes her; he want to ML with her.

男人约会迟到的原因:一是睡`过了`；二是`睡过`了。

Reason of a boy was late for appointment: wake up late(oversleep); was slept with the girl.

P.S. 英语不好，希望能看懂 O(∩_∩)O~

P.S. My English is not very good, I hope you can understand. O(∩_∩)O~

Answer (score 0):

These are some interesting Chinese wording and grammar patterns
冬天能穿多少穿多少：多少is one word as a whole. 夏天能穿多少穿多少：多is an adv. for 少

谁都看不上：谁in this sentence could be sub. or obj. In Chinese obj. may be not following verb, but at the beginning

一个人：may be someone (refer to other person), or being alone (refer to oneself)

喜欢上：上could be a 助词 (English has no such part of speech) for 喜欢, means "have fallen in love", or a verb (oral using only, means f**k)，喜欢is the predicate, means "love to f**k"

睡 could be sleep, also, only in oral using, could be f**k. 睡过means "slept for too long", or "f**ked"